# Preformatted text with linebreaks in source but not in output

Tags: javadoc, word-wrap

In Javadoc, how do I line-wrap a long line within <pre> tags without affecting the output?

Our company code guidelines state that a source file should not be wider than 80 characters, but I have a line like this:

```
/**
 * <pre>new {@link LongClassName}(10, new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};</pre>
 */
```

The line, rendered in html, is not very long, but in javadoc it reaches column 91.

When I wrap the javadoc, there'll also be a line break in the browser, which I don't want.